# How to call a native mobile app that read barcode and return it's data to HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, barcode

There're couple of possibilities which completely not solved my problem yet.

- First I tried to use PhoneGap but I can't use it anymore because of IndexedDB issues currently it has.
- Then I switched to the option to call a native mobile application from a web page that can read a barcode.
- Eventually this native application has to return barcode data it's
  read, in order to make use of it within web app.

I couldn't figure it out properly and appreciate if someone can explain this if it's possible. Some of the questions I looked at as of now;

- [barcode scanning in web apps for smartphone/tablet browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714419/barcode-scanning-in-web-apps-for-smartphone-tablet-browsers?rq=1)
- [How to open a native iOS app from a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237031/how-to-open-a-native-ios-app-from-a-web-app/40487091#40487091)

Comment: firstly, there is no default system app to do that. Only 3rd-party apps can read QR codes. Also I'm not sure you can call the externall app, and make it provide you with a result

Comment: With phonegap and [barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) it is super easy. Maybe could be better find a way for workaround the indexDB problems?

Comment: Might help by looking at other apps and how they integrate. Please see the documentation for integration http://scannrapp.com/

Comment: Hey @VladyslavMatviienko, I was taking a look at past and realized the question is unanswered. Since your comment is the answer rather than other solutions, I want you to share your comment as an answer to be accepted by me. It'd be more appropriate I suppose rather than my own answer to be accepted (:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since commentator not answered even it's the real answer, I'm answering my own question to be shared openly.

Even it's possible to call another application to read barcode, it's not possible to turn back to the same app with this 3rd party app if it's not also managed by you directly.

So the alternatives may vary depending upon the specific situation but I had to let user make the 3rd party app to read barcode, and then wait user to turn back to my originated application after getting these results linked to my website.